# if condition checking multiple vector sizes are equal

Tags: c++, c++17

I have 4 different vectors and I need to check whether all 4 vector sizes are equal. I have the below piece of code but I'm looking for a better version.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4;
if ((vec1.size() == vec2.size())
    && (vec3.size() == vec4.size())
    && (vec1.size() == vec4.size()))
{
    std::cout << "equal";
}
```

Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: As long as objects are not part of a container, it's very hard to manipulate them uniformly. For example, you could make a vector of pointer to vectors, but at that point, is it worth it? Either way you'll need to name them all individually. Consider making your individual vectors into an `std::array` of vectors.

Comment: What is wrong with your code that is making you seek a "better" way?

Comment: You could use a vector of vectors and a loop

Comment: @nicol in future the number of vector may increase. so felt like not great code

Comment: @Arun: If they're loose variables, then there isn't really a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this I guess:

```
template <typename T0, typename... Ts>
bool areSameSize(T0 const& first, Ts const&... rest) {
    return ((first.size() == rest.size()) && ...);
}
```

Used like `areSameSize(vec1, vec2, vec3, vec4)`.